# Assignin $this in non-object scope

Tags: php, oop

Are there any disadvantages of assigning something to `$this` in a non-object scope?

```
<?php
// begin of index.php
$this = new Bootstrap();
```

I want to act like beeing inside of an instance from the beginning of the program.

Is this considered a good idea?

Comment: You want to "act like you're in an instance"? But you're not. What do you expect to happen by acting "as if you are"?

Comment: It doesn't matter, it won't work. ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's considered a bad idea because it doesn't work:

```
php > $this = 'foo';
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot re-assign $this in php shell code on line 1
```

`$this` is special, you can't use it where you're not supposed to use it.